# Is this grammatically acceptable? "Defined by its being identical to"

Tags: grammar, possessive-pronouns

I just wrote this sentence,

> As the strategy is defined by its being identical to the existing strategy, with a few
> notable exceptions, I have to use a particular technique to implement it.

This is quite a weird phrasing but I'm sure I've heard something similar to this before.  Is this actually grammatically acceptable?  If so, under what rule?  (Not worried about whether it's "good writing", just wondering if it's technically acceptable or not.)

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=defined+by+it+being%2Cdefined+by+its+being&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), both your "possessive" version *(...by **its** being...)* and the "flat" version *(...by **it** being...)* are in common use (and I'll stick my neck out and say they're ***always*** equivalent). The possessive version is definitely *more* common, but I'd say it's essentially a stylistic choice.

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [Possessive gerund usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245323/possessive-gerund-usage)

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but most people reading it will be suffering.